# Deferred callback not being called using Python requests-threads

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, twisted, deferred

I am trying to perform async HTTP requests by using the requests library in Python. I found that the last version of the library does not directly support async requets. To achive it they provide the requests-threads library that makes use of Twisted to handle asynchronicity. I tried modifying the examples provided to use callbacks instead of await/yield, but the callbacks are not being called.

My sample code is:

```
session = AsyncSession(n=10)

def processResponse(response):
  print(response)

def main():
  a = session.get('https://reqres.in/api/users')
  a.addCallbacks(processResponse, processResponse)
  time.sleep(5)
```

The requests-threads library: https://github.com/requests/requests-threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the callbacks are not called because you aren't running Twisted's eventloop (known as the `reactor`). Remove your sleep function and replace it with `reactor.run()`.

```py
from twisted.internet import reactor
# ...
def main():
    a = session.get('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    a.addCallbacks(processResponse, processResponse)
    #time.sleep(5)    # never use blocking functions like this w/ Twisted
    reactor.run()
```

The catch is Twisted's reactor cannot be restarted, so once you stop the event loop (ie. `reactor.stop()`), an exception will be raised when `reactor.run()` is executed again. In other words, your script/app will only "run once". To circumvent this issue, I suggest you use [`crochet`](https://crochet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html). Here's a quick example using a similar example from `requests-thread`:

```py
import crochet
crochet.setup()
print('setup')

from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from requests_threads import AsyncSession

session = AsyncSession(n=100)

@crochet.run_in_reactor
@inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor):
    responses = []
    for i in range(10):
        responses.append(session.get('http://httpbin.org/get'))

    for response in responses:
        r = yield response
        print(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event = main(None)
    event.wait()
```

And just as an FYI `requests-thread` is not for production systems and is subject to significant change (as of Oct 2017). The end goal of this project is to design an awaitable design pattern for `requests` in the future. If you need production ready concurrent requests, consider `grequests` or `treq`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only mistake here is that you forgot to run the [reactor/event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111265/how-does-pythons-twisted-reactor-work).

The following code works for me:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from requests_threads import AsyncSession

session = AsyncSession(n=10)


def processResponse(response):
    print(response)


a = session.get('https://reqres.in/api/users')
a.addCallbacks(processResponse, processResponse)
reactor.run()
```